# Django/PDF изоброжение не грузится

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pdf

Прошу помочь, посмотрел кучу туторилав и форумов, только вы поможете

есть заранее написанный на бутстрапе html хочу генерировать в pdf что бы сразу скачал, скажу заранее что у меня там изоброжение и кириллица

как мне достичь целей, попробовал reportlab и xhtml2pdf, ну никак.

Comment: webkit или другой безголовый бразузер пробовал?

Comment: @eri не понял, как можно через браузер?

Comment: А можно и через браузер на клиенте отрисовать пдф. На сервере это делается через движок браузера в безоконном режиме... Доки если будет время найти - напишу ответ

Comment: @eri буду очень блогодарен, если поможете примерами, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ, может кому то пригодится
окозалось все очень просто!

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
import pdfkit
def pdf(request,id):
    bus = Buses.objects.get(id=id)
    template = get_template('buses/pdf.html')
    html = template.render({'bus': bus})
    options = {
        'page-size': 'Letter',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
    }

    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options)
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="driver_{}_route_{}.pdf"'.format(bus.name, bus.route)

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно установить на сервер браузер, например хром.

Дальше в джанге запускаешь процессом

```
import os
os.system('chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="path/to/pdf" file:///path/bootstrrap.html')
```

Также можно попробовать

https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/ - обертка

https://habr.com/ru/post/128078/ - нужен икс сервер, не очень хорошее решение, но описанно

Comment: у меня же там определенного html файлика же нет, я рендрею после чего появляется пример localhost:8000/detail/3  получается треться страничка с обьектмаи третьего id, как нет других способов?

Comment: Так передай ссылку на эту страничку браузеру

Comment: Я бы через print на жс сохранял